# Python calling a function that creates directory does not work as expected

Tags: python, django

I am calling a function inside my Django view. The code works but not when calling the function inside the view. I have simplified the code.

```
import os
    
def MakeDir(path):
    try:
        os.mkdir(path)
        #... some more logic...
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)

def MydjView(request):
    MakeDir('/tmp/year') #function call but directory is not created
    return HttpResponse('okay')
```

Comment: Could you please paste the error message or error response ?

Comment: I'd remove the try/except so you can see the problem exception

Comment: I actually use try / except to handle directory exists error. This is closer to my real code. I get errors in the console that directory exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `os.mkdir(path)`. You can immediately check if the dir was created:

```
os.mkdir(path)
print(os.listdir(path))  # this will be an empty string if it worked.
```

If you get a `FileExistsError` from `mkdir`, the folder exists already.

If you get a `FileNotFound` error from `listdir`, the folder wasn't actually created.

If you get no exceptions, it's working as expected.